# Creating IPSet in python program

Tags: python

I want to write python code that takes as input a  traffic pattern (i.e. an IP range, port and protocol) and determines whether the pattern is accepted or rejected by a firewall policy.

I think using IPSets would help. In particular, I thought of using `hash:net,port`

When I try to create such a set in my code, I get an invalid syntax error.

This is the syntax I am using:

```
ipset -N -exist contract hash:net,port
```

I also tried:

```
ipset create -exist contract hash:net,port
```

Comment: You can take a look on https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Comment: I need to perform set operations (set minus, union, intersection). Would the ipaddress module support that?

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Can you show us your code?  Those commands aren't Python syntax, so if you tried that verbatim it's no surprise you received a syntax error.  Include your code and the exact error message you are receiving. It may not be possible to do what you want; the kernel firewall tools don't generally provide facilities for testing a ruleset in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Adding and removing set elements:
    s1 = IPSet()
    s1.add('192.0.2.0')
    IPSet(['192.0.2.0/32'])
Here is a simple arbitrary IP address range:
    iprange = IPRange('192.0.1.255', '192.0.2.16')
We can see the CIDR networks that can existing with this defined range:
    iprange.cidrs()
    [IPNetwork('192.0.1.255/32')
    IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/28')
    IPNetwork('192.0.2.16/32')]
```